# How to set camera orientation locked to portrait on android

Tags: java, android, scanning

I'm building a scanner app using [this scan library](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo), how do I set the orientation in the library code to set the camera orientation locked to portrait? I've tried
 [Lock Camera orientation to portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700226/lock-camera-orientation-to-portrait)  and 
[setting camera orientation to portrait not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224354/setting-camera-orientation-to-portrait-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use third party libs

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera

You can use the official android docs to learn how to use and then apply what you got from the other links. If you want to edit and crop you cand find more information in those links:

[How to crop and rotate image programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571509/how-to-crop-and-rotate-image-programmatically-in-android)

[Android: Edit image intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699299/android-edit-image-intent)